# How can i change the scale of text written on the PDF (scaleX and scaleY)?

Tags: java, android

As we can change the scale of text written on textview, i want to change the scale of the text written on PDF(the PDF is created by me in android studio).

I was using paint.scale(something) but it does not having this function.

Comment: check this : https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24522/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-the-size-of-the-text-when-reading-pdf-files

Comment: Thank you sir, but i need to change the scale like only height of text or only width of the text. Like in android text view we have the option of TextView.scaleX or TextView.scaleY, do we have any possibility to make it in PDF. Like while i am creating a PDF i am using paint but there is not any option for scaling that text.  like paint.scaleX  or paint.scaleY

Comment: Ok, I've not tried before, but maybe it works :  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166476/android-canvas-drawtext-set-font-size-from-width