# Android. Font size too large to fit in cache

Tags: android, fonts, size

I want to adjust app font size to device size. I have values, values-hdpi, values-ldpi.. folders and added there dimens.xml file and set dimens like this `<dimen name="task_check_box_font">16sp</dimen>`.
But then I get

> font size to large to fit in cache error.

How to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253528/font-size-too-large-to-fit-in-cache

Comment: No. There get error, because uses big font. Mine normal, just 16sp

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

**Create ScreenWidth.java**

```
public class ScreenWidth {

    public ScreenWidth(){}

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public int getScreenWidth(Context context) {
        int columnWidth ;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        final Point point = new Point();
        try {
            display.getSize(point);
        } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) { // Older device
            point.x = display.getWidth();
            point.y = display.getHeight();
        }   

        columnWidth = point.x;


        return columnWidth;
    }

}
```

now create object of above class to get screen size pragmatically.

```
ScreenWidth SW = new ScreenWidth();
int width_sc =SW.getScreenWidth(this);
TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
t1.setTextSize(((width_sc*22)/768));
```

Hope this may help you!