# Text in TextView with large font not displayed on some devices

Tags: java, android, textview, large-fonts

I have the TextView contains remaining time of timer that must fit its bounds, i.e. less text == larger font
On other devices all are ok, but on ASUS Zenfone 4(ASUS_T00I, 4.4.2, 480x800, hdpi) text stops displaying when font size is bigger then some limit (see screens)

**IMPORTANT:** Not duplicate of [Font size too large to fit in cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253528/font-size-too-large-to-fit-in-cache) 

I have the similar issue (**that i have already solved**) on another device with logs:

```
ERROR/OpenGLRenderer(2503): Font size to large to fit in cache.
```

This was solved by this code from question above in my TextView:

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

But not solved **this** issue

Screens
2 screens above are made on LG G3, and this is how it looks like on other devices
2 screens below are made on ASUS Zenfone 4

[image]

Comment: So there are no log messages that correspond to this? Could it simply be a fraction too large to fit in the textview.

Comment: You could give this a go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds?rq=1

Comment: @weston, 
1) No, there is no any logs.  
2) No, fact text size is always less then bounds of textview (if it were so, I would have seen only a fraction, that fits in bounds).  
3) i've already tried this lib on this device, same result.  
Thx for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solutions,

set `setLayerType` for your TextView

```
TextView bigText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bigtext);
bigText.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

or add `android:hardwareAccelerated` from manifest.

```
<application
    android:...
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
    <activity ...>
```