# how to put text on image bitmap at bottom?

Tags: android, canvas, android-imageview, android-canvas, android-bitmap

**What I Want:** I want to add text at bottom of a image which I have chose from either gallery or camera.

**Original Image**

[image: Original Image]

**I added blue color strip to image at bottom**

[image: I added little strip to image at bottom]

In that strip, I want to add some text exactly in middle.

**What's the Problem:**

1. I'm unable to position text exactly in middle of blue color strip.
2. For different images, text size changes. Some time it is very small, some time it is very big.

**What I Tried:** My code is like below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public void openGallery(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 100);
    }

    public void openCamera(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (data != null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == 100) {

                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media
                            .getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                addStampToImage(bitmap);

            } else if (requestCode == 101) {

                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                addStampToImage(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addStampToImage(Bitmap originalBitmap) {

        int extraHeight = (int) (originalBitmap.getHeight() * 0.15);

        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap.getWidth(),
                originalBitmap.getHeight() + extraHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        Resources resources = getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;

        Paint pText = new Paint();
        pText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        pText.setTextSize((int) (20 * scale));

        String text = "Maulik";

        /*Rect r = new Rect();
        canvas.getClipBounds(r);
        int cHeight = r.height();
        int cWidth = r.width();
        pText.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        pText.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), r);
        float x = -r.left;
        float y = cHeight / 2f + r.height() / 2f - r.bottom;

        int minusSpace = (int) (canvas.getClipBounds().bottom * 0.07);

        canvas.drawText(text, 0, canvas.getClipBounds().bottom - minusSpace, pText);*/

        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        pText.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        int x = (newBitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width())/6;
        int y = (newBitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height())/5;

        canvas.drawText(text, x * scale, y * scale, pText);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

**Updated: 1st Aug 2018**

Changes in **addStampToImage** method.

```
int extraHeight = (int) (originalBitmap.getHeight() * 0.15);

Rect textHeightWidth = new Rect();
pText.getTextBounds(fromWhichMode, 0, fromWhichMode.length(), textHeightWidth);

canvas.drawText(textToStamp, (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (textHeightWidth.width() / 2),
                originalBitmap.getHeight() + (extraHeight / 2) + (textHeightWidth.height() / 2),
                pText);
```

Above changes giving me text in middle of blue strip. But core **ISSUE** remains same. i.e Text size changes with respect to different image sizes.

Comment: Does your bitmap width and height both will change dynamically or only width or only height?

Comment: Yes, it will change. It depends upon which image I'm choosing via **Gallery** or **Camera**@Nainal

Comment: Are you able to correctly place the text i.e, at the center of blue strip. As I have checked your code and it is not placing the text in correct position?

Comment: Yes. I can. I will update the question.

Comment: @Nainal I updated the question.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the text size changes? The same happens with me, for an image from camera text size is correct, but for some random image from the gallery the text size increase abruptly :(

Comment: @iCantC: No, I did not able to solve the issue. May be you can check some library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the  below code:-

```
private void addStampToImage(Bitmap originalBitmap) {

    int extraHeight = (int) (originalBitmap.getHeight() * 0.15);

    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap.getWidth(),
            originalBitmap.getHeight() + extraHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    Resources resources = getResources();
    float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;

    String text = "Maulik";
    Paint pText = new Paint();
    pText.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    setTextSizeForWidth(pText,(int) (originalBitmap.getHeight() * 0.10),text);




    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    pText.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

    int x=  ((newBitmap.getWidth()-(int)pText.measureText(text))/2);
    int h=(extraHeight+bounds.height())/2;
    int y=(originalBitmap.getHeight()+h);

    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, pText);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
}


private void setTextSizeForWidth(Paint paint, float desiredHeight,
                                        String text) {

    // Pick a reasonably large value for the test. Larger values produce
    // more accurate results, but may cause problems with hardware
    // acceleration. But there are workarounds for that, too; refer to
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253528/font-size-too-large-to-fit-in-cache
    final float testTextSize = 48f;

    // Get the bounds of the text, using our testTextSize.
    paint.setTextSize(testTextSize);
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

    // Calculate the desired size as a proportion of our testTextSize.
    float desiredTextSize = testTextSize * desiredHeight / bounds.height();

    // Set the paint for that size.
    paint.setTextSize(desiredTextSize);
}
```

**Edit:-**
Instead of above addStampToImage method you can also use your updated addStampToImage method like below:-

```
private void addStampToImage(Bitmap originalBitmap) {

    int extraHeight = (int) (originalBitmap.getHeight() * 0.15);

    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap.getWidth(),
            originalBitmap.getHeight() + extraHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    Resources resources = getResources();
    float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;

    String text = "Maulik";
    Paint pText = new Paint();
    pText.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    setTextSizeForWidth(pText,(int) (originalBitmap.getHeight() * 0.10),text);


    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    pText.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

    Rect textHeightWidth = new Rect();
    pText.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textHeightWidth);

    canvas.drawText(text, (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (textHeightWidth.width() / 2),
            originalBitmap.getHeight() + (extraHeight / 2) + (textHeightWidth.height() / 2),
            pText);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
}
```

Comment: Let me check, I will revert you.

Comment: It is looking great. Let me check for other images as well. Thanks.

Comment: @MaulikDodia Ok

Answer (score 0):

try this one i think help to you

/**
     * FOR WATER-MARK
     */

```
public static Bitmap waterMark(Bitmap src, String watermark, Point location, int color, int alpha, int size, boolean underline) {
            int[] pixels = new int[100];

            //get source image width and height
            int widthSreen = src.getWidth();   // 1080L // 1920
            int heightScreen = src.getHeight();  // 1343L  // 2387


            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthSreen, heightScreen, src.getConfig());
            //create canvas object
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
            //draw bitmap on canvas
            canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
            //create paint object
            Paint paint = new Paint();
    //        //apply color
    //        paint.setColor(color);
    //        //set transparency
    //        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    //        //set text size
            size = ((widthSreen * 5) / 100);
            paint.setTextSize(size);
    //        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    //        //set should be underlined or not
    //        paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
    //
    //        //draw text on given location
    //        //canvas.drawText(watermark, w / 4, h / 2, paint);

            Paint.FontMetrics fm = new Paint.FontMetrics();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    //        paint.setTextSize(18.0f);
            paint.getFontMetrics(fm);
            int margin = 5;
            canvas.drawRect(50 - margin, 50 + fm.top - margin,
                    50 + paint.measureText(watermark) + margin, 50 + fm.bottom
                            + margin, paint);

            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawText(watermark, 50, 50, paint);
            return result;
        }
```

call this method on your onActivityResult

```
 Bitmap bitmapp = waterMark(bitmap, your_string, p, Color.RED, 90, 90, true);
```

Comment: Let me check. BTW Thanks.

Comment: Getting same issue with your code as well. Text size changes if image is of different size@Saif

Comment: then you can set fix size or text  : Change this 2 lines : 
size = 40; \\Or any size you want
paint.setTextSize(size);

Comment: What you are saying is, I have already tried. I think you did not get my question. Can refer it again? Text written on image should look of same size for different size images@Saif

Comment: @MaulikDodia same issue from my side any idea?

Comment: @Mr.vickypatel: No brother